# Difference between Prism Dialogs vs Popup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, dialog, prism

I am implementing Prism in a new Xamarin Forms App. I have been using Rg.Plugins.Popup in the app before converting to Prism.

What are the limitation on the Prism Dialogs vs Prism.Plugin.Popups?

What are some examples when you would use one over the other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rg.Plugins.Popup is a popular plugin for Xamarin.Forms which accesses the native functionality to provide a "Modal Popup" which traditionally has not been achievable with Xamarin.Forms.

### Dialogs in Prism 7.2

If you're using Prism 7.2 you'll find that the DialogService locates the currently displayed page and then "reparent's the content". Or in other words it takes the content of the active Content Page and places it as the root child of an AbsoluteLayout, placing a mask layer and finally your dialog on top. As a result of this approach you'll notice that any navigation bars for instance on the NavigationPage or TabbedPage, or a MasterDetailPage's menu will remain accessible to the user.

While in some regard both the PopupPage and Dialog may look very similar as you can probably tell there is some significant divergence there.

### Dialogs in Prism 8

If you're using Prism 8.0 you'll see that we have updated to the latest Xamarin.Forms and as a result we are able to take advantage of a new feature in Xamarin.Forms which allows you to present a Modal Page with a Transparent background. This in effect allows you to replicate the effect of a PopupPage with either some benefits or drawbacks depending on how you look at it.

1. With Rg.Plugins.Popups you have the ability to push a PopupPage on top of whatever page is currently displayed from anywhere in the app
2. With Xamarin.Forms page's that have been pushed Modally they are part of your active Navigation Stack
3. Using the a traditional page with a transparent background and Modal Navigation you in effect have replicated the appearance of what you get with a PopupPage

### Limitations

- Prism.Plugin.Popups has the benefit of being integrated into the Navigation Service. As such you can inject the Navigation Service into the ViewModel of a PopupPage, and the PopupPage will be dismissed when you navigate away from it to another non PopupPage.
- Dialogs are not part of the Navigation Stack tracked by Prism's Navigation Service. Navigation in Xamarin.Forms is dependent on navigating FROM a specific page. Since Prism's NavigationService doesn't know about the Dialog you will need to dismiss the dialog before navigating.

### Other Key Differences

Besides what I've mentioned so far the only real difference is that Rg.Plugins.Popup gives you some added animations which honestly I've seen very few people using.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!